# How do I make this code shorter and more efficient?

Tags: c, cs50, credit-card, luhn

This is my solution for the Credit problem on CS50's Pset1. It involves using Luhn's Algorithm to test the validity of the Credit Card Number entered and based on a few conditions attempts to identify the Credit Card Company.

Check_Length attempts to find the length of the number entered.
Check_Company attempts to ID the company.
Check_Luhn validates the number based on Luhn's Algorithm.

I'd like to know if this could be done with fewer lines of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int check_length(long);
void check_company(int,long);
bool check_luhn(long,int);
int length;

int main(void)
{
        long c = get_long("Enter Credit Card Number: ");
        check_length(c);
        check_luhn(c,length);
        if(check_luhn(c,length)==true)
        {
                check_company(length,c);
        }
        else printf("INVALID\n");

}

int check_length(long w)
{
        for(int i=12;i<16;i++)
        {
                long power = 1;
                for (int k=1;k<i+1;k++)
                {
                        power = power * 10;
                }
                int scale = w/power;
                if (scale<10 && scale>0)
                {
                        length = i+1;
                }              
       }    
       return length;
}

void check_company(int x,long z)
{
        if(x == 15)
        {
                int y = z/10000000000000;           //z/10^13
                if(y==34||y==37)
                {
                        printf("AMEX\n");
                }
                else
                {
                printf("INVALID\n");
                }
        }
        else if(x==13)
        {
                int y = z/100000000000;                 //z/10^11
                if(y==4)
                {
                       printf("VISA\n");
                }
         }
         else if(x==16)
         {
                 int q = z/1000000000000000;
                 int y = z/100000000000000;
                 if(y==51||y==52||y==53||y==54||y==55)
                 {
                         printf("MASTERCARD\n");
                 }
                 else             
                 if(q==4)
                 {
                         printf("VISA\n");
                 }
                 else printf("INVALID\n");
         }
         else printf("INVALID\n");
}

bool check_luhn(long a,int b)
{
         int f = 0;
         int j=0;
         for(int d=1;d<b+1;d++)
         {    
                 int e = a%10;
                 a = a/10;
                 if(d%2==1)
                 {
                        f = f+e;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                         int m = 2*e;
                         int g = m%10;
                         int h = m/10;
                         j = j+g+h;
                  }

          }
          int l = j + f;
          if(l%10==0)
          {
                 return true;
          }
          else return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't look too much at lines of code as metric for efficient code. The single improvement I can see is to store the credit card number as a string, not as a long number. This catches numbers that have leading zeros, you can allow hyphens and spaces in input (and then "normalize" it), because that's how people enter cc numbers, and it allows you to access individual digits without performing arithmetic digit extraction.

Comment: If the code works (give expected results with no errors), you could post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for an exhaustive review.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This might be better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: Sure, John. I'll post it there. Do I need to delete this question?